# Using future simple vs future perfect

Tags: tenses

Future simple :
We will finish the project by next year

Future perfect :
We will have finished the project by next year

I've been told that Future perfect must be used when 'by' exists. But for some reason, future perfect doesn't seem natural to use here. Perhaps due to my years of bad spoken english experience. May I ask which tense to use when somebody asks about the time it takes to finish a project ?

Comment: Please cite the authority that claims *by* must be used with the future perfect, as well as the actual wording of the claim itself. As presented, it isn't correct - there's nothing wrong with the grammar of "We will finish by the evening" or of "We would have finished by the evening had things gone to plan".

Comment: @Lawrence - I'm coming from [this video](https://youtu.be/X8s1RsvYw5I?t=3339) . In that he uses the exact same example in future perfect. For me, it looked a bit odd to use future perfect for the stated situation, so I've asked about the same here...

Comment: The future perfect works with *by* in his second example, but I wouldn't elevate it to a 'rule'.

Comment: Thank you @Lawrence I think I see now why it is just a guideline and not a rule. It's to do with the semantics I guess. Future perfect seems to convey something will be done before some date, and this date has some pre existing special meaning to everyone involved.)

Comment: In future simple the date has no special meaning. It could be any date... I may be wrong, but this contrast between both the tenses fits with my model... Do you maybe suggest any simple grammar book which emphasizes differences like these ?

Comment: Also covered at [Should I use 'by' as a preposition of time in past / future perfect tenses only?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193383/should-i-use-by-as-a-preposition-of-time-in-past-future-perfect-tenses-only) and [specific and unspecific future: use of 'tenses' with 'by'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90924/specific-and-unspecific-future).

Comment: Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote from *Cambridge Advanced Grammar in Use, 2002* Unit15: "We use the Fut.Perfect to say that something will be ended, completed, or achieved by *a particular point* in the future."

So you can use this tense if you want to stress the idea of completeness. Yes, 'by' could be a useful signal, but the presence of 'by' doesn't mean that you MUST use a particular tense.